# collecting CLI usage data with python click

Tags: python, logging, command-line-interface

I'm a platform engineer building a python CLI app (using click) that teams in the same company could use to launch data processing jobs on our internally managed cluster.

I want to build a functionality to collect usage data i.e., record the commands submitted to the app and store them in a database.

Something like this:

```py
import click

@click.group()
@click.option("--environment", help="cluster to use")
def app():
    ...

@app.command()
@click.option("--file-path", required=True)
def run():
    # if a user runs "$ app --environment development run --file-path test.py"
    # we should retrieve the command as is
    # and store it somewhere
    # Question: how do I get the complete command?
    ...
```

Is it possible? Is there an established pattern for collecting CLI usage data in python?

Comment: There is no established pattern if you don't tell us where "somewhere" is. But you can of course just send `sys.argv` _somewhere_.

Comment: @AKX As long as I could retrieve the full command, how is the storage layer relevant? but for the sake of it, suppose I'm using cloud storage like BigQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter if you use `click` or `typer` or `argparse` or nothing at all, you can find the whole command line in [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

For a `click.group()` app, you could store the command line in the group callback:

```
import click
import sys

@click.group()
@click.option("--environment", help="cluster to use")
def app():
    save_command(sys.argv)


def save_command(args: list[str]):
    ...
```

I'd recommend scrubbing the command of any potential secrets before sending them over, of course.